# Play wav file in linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, media, wav

I know that this question is a duplicate. But in other questions, people advise `Phonon` which is not available in Qt 5+ (I'm using 5.4).

I also tried to use `QAudioOutput`:

```
    QFile inputFile;
    inputFile.setFileName("/home/efog/G6_Build/sound.wav");
    inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setSampleRate(44100);
    format.setChannelCount(2);
    format.setSampleSize(16);
    format.setCodec("audio/wav");

    QAudioOutput *audio = new QAudioOutput( format, 0);
    audio->start(&inputFile);
```

But it is not working, same as `QSound`:

```
    QSound::play("/home/efog/G6_Build/sound.wav");
```

`NAS` and `GStreamer` are installed. So, how can I play `wav` files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing WAV Files in Qt 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534226/playing-wav-files-in-qt-5-3)

Comment: Read carefully: i wrote, that QSound didnt worked for me.

Comment: I have the same problem, QSound does not support all WAV files. This question needs an answer already

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes QSound takes some time to play when it first loads the file. Try creating a QSound object with the file, and playing it afterwards, and maybe give it a little time.

```
QSound *sound = new QSound("/home/efog/G6_Build/sound.wav");
sound->play();
```

And are you sure, your wav file is really a wav file? I've seen audio files with wav extension, but actually they were mp3 files. Maybe try with another audio file first.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't helped. About wav: `efog@homebox:~$ file sound.wav`give me that 
`sound.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 96000 Hz`

Comment: from the linux command line you can verify whether the WAV file renders correctly, just type in :   avplay  yourfile.wav    avplay is part of avconv which is handy to have installed for any sound related projects ... sox is another great command line tool which also gives you the command :  play youtfile.wav ... enjoy

Comment: @Efog, sorry if it's obvious, but have you tried with another wav file? I want to understand if the problem is with the audio file.

Comment: @Efog See my last edit. (Sorry, removed the last edit, it was wrong.

Comment: You might need to install some gstreamer-plugins. For example gstreamer-plugins-good, gstreamer-plugins-bad etc.